# Steam VR (Teleport Prefab) doesnt work with one controller on

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR0pi.png)I am trying to build an app with a simple teleport system using Steam VR teleportation. The controller appears but nothing happens when the Vive Controller is activated. Once both are on they both run properly and the teleporter arc is both visible and works well.The app has to work with only one controller ,please help me with any ideas as to how to decouple these two controllers so that my project can use only one controller when the other controller is off.

Comment: can you give us a sample of the code u have that is where the problem is to try help you out?

Comment: @Fuzzybear thanks for the response,the thing is there isnt really any sample code. Its the basic steam vr setup including teleportation.and the teleportation only work with both controllers on